# Why can't I see an iPad version of my app in App Store if this app is universal?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I created and submitted my Universal app in App Store. However, when I search this app from iPad, it cannot be found in the "iPad only" section. To download it, I have to change the search filter to "iPhone only" and find it there.

Did I do something wrong or is it how App Store works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was temporary. When you add an iPad version for your iPhone app it takes several hours after its release to appear in "iPad only". So I just had to wait for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You should submit iPad screenshots if you want your app to be visible on the iPad's App Store by default.

In iTunes Connect, navigate to **My Apps/[your app]/App Store/[app version]/Version Information/App Previews and Screenshots**, select **iPad** and upload some screenshots.

[image: Version Information/App Previews and Screenshots]

Comment: Here's a [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mip/id1256575819?ls=1&mt=8) to my app if it can help you in some way.